# can I add ubuntu liveusb to a "windows recovery" usb?

Tags: live-usb, windows-10

I have made LiveUSB sticks for various versions of Ubuntu.
Now I have also made a Windows 10 Recovery USB bootable stick.

Can I add LiveUSB to that Windows stick?
Building the Windows Recovery USB took a long time, so I'd rather just carry two sticks than break the Windows stick.

Comment: No, at least not easily.

Comment: Windows = complicated. Windows Recovery = complicated x 2. Why would you want to complicate it more by putting non-Windows onto a Windows stick? A better use of time would be to take a LiveUSB and make it a Live USB with 10 GB or 26 GB or 58 GB of persistence storage, depending on if it is a 16 GB, 32 GB or 64 GB stick.

Comment: *Building the Windows Recovery USB took a long time*. You can always make a disk image of your USB, and just restore it when necessary. It's not like you need it every day.

Comment: Installing GRUB in your USB you can make a multiboot, I've done it with windows 7/10 installers, but im not sure with the windows recovery. If it boots in the same way as the installers, is technically doable, although it's kind of *relatively* complicated stuff.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix it makes sense when you want a multipurpose USB. Windows installers for example take 4 or 5 gigs, in a 8gb USB, you would have a lot of space for other tools (clonezilla, gparted, rescatux, and/or a linux distro or two).

Comment: I've reconsidered.
I'll keep good quality sticks for my Ubuntu live.

5 pack of 8 GB for $22.99 for the seldom used images.

https://www.staples.com/Verbatim-5PK-8GB-Pinstripe-USB-2-0-Red-Blue-Green-Purple-Teal/product_1913050

Answer (score 0):

There are apps (both Windows and Linux) which allow making a multiple-Linux LiveUSB, so you can have Live images of multiple releases of Ubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu Core, Ubuntu Kylin, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Studio, Kubuntu, Lubuntu and Xubuntu, all on one LiveUSB. Here's a [handy review](https://www.linuxbabe.com/apps/create-multiboot-usb-linux-windows-iso) of some of them.

Windows apps to generate multiboot LiveUSBs: [Multiboot](http://multibootusb.org/page_download/), [Multisystem](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/), [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) [Sardu Pro](https://www.sarducd.it/downloads) (not free) and [WinSetupFromUSB](http://www.winsetupfromusb.com/downloads/).

Linux GUI apps to generate multiboot Live USBs: [Multiboot](http://multibootusb.org/page_download/) and [Sardu Pro](https://www.sarducd.it/downloads) (not free). It can also be done from the command line, but I don't have time now to research that.

Adding Windows to the USB, however, is more complex, for Windows 10 is designed not to run from a LiveUSB; what you find on a Windows USB is an installation package which doubles as a recovery package.